# Can I import villager trading values to another player/level.dat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had to make a villager hall on my survival world and noticed that I was on the world with the wrong account and switched my account. When I loaded up the world, I had the same items, everything looks like normal, but the prices that villagers gave me for healing them disappeared and my tame animals like dogs and cats don't sit/wander when I order the to. I thought it might be because of my `player.dat`/`level.dat` and I could just <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> something using NBTexplorer or Universal Minecraft Editor but I don't know what I am supposed to search for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure of the exact details but I believe that this information is stored on the villager, not on the player. So you would have to go into each villagers data individually and modify it to give the discounts to the new account.